# Bootstrap: side by side labels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the best way to reproduce the side-by-side labels in the image below using bootstrap?

[image]

Comment: How you tried to achieve that, can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What wrong with something as simple as this

```
<div class="container" style="max-width: 300px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      Broker Fee:
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6 text-right">
      $1,00.00
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      Premium:
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6 text-right">
      $1,800.00
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      Taxes/Fees:
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6 text-right">
      $224.00
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ezhudo2

Comment: I tried this approach as well, but it lines up the columns in a grid. I need my labels to be side by side as in Policy Number label above. I started looking into Bootstrap Forms to see if horizontal layout could help, but most documentation only references labels + input controls. I did find a section in the documentation about static content, but I'm sure I'm going down the wrong path.